# How to disable Xvid status window

Tags: registry

I would like to disable the Xvid status window that is shown during recording. I know how to disable it via configuration dialog, but I would like to disable it when my app is installed on computer. Based on some searching it could be possible to disable it via windows registry, but I'm not able to find any info on how to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "when my app is installed on computer"?

Comment: I meant to disable it with installer. I use Inno setup and can add/modify registry key/values.